# Cannot rewrite file in folder (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, filesystems

In Flutter (Android), I open a File object, write to it adding bytes using the IOSink object and the file is created in the specified folder and everything is great. Now, I delete manually the file. Run the program again and try to write a new file again to the same folder with the same name. The file isn't created, nor it appears in the folder. What is the problem that I am missing here?